# 500 Internal error with .htaccess only on localhost - redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have the following .htacess file to remove the .php extension and to create SEO Friendly URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On 

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

This works absolutely fine when hosted on our domain, but when I test locally on our localhost server it comes up with Error 500, Internal Server Error.

In my httpd.conf file, the rewrite module is uncommented:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

The Apache Error Log states:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://localhost:8888/Website/
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is definitely due to looping.

Your first rule is removing `.php` extension. Then 404 handler and 2nd rule is sending everything to `.php` files hence looping will go on.

To avoid you can use these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /Website/

ErrorDocument 404 /Website/404.php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+/Website/(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Note use if `%{THE_REQUEST}` instead of `RewriteRule`. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't change by application of other rules.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but it seems to have the same issue.

Comment: Is there any other rule OR any other .htaccess also?

Comment: No, what you see in the htaccess file I posted in the OP is what's in my .htaccess file. It seems odd that it works on my domain, but not on localhost.

Comment: OK Can you add `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews` line on top.

Comment: Just tried adding it at the very top and also tried below "RewriteEngine On".. No avail.

Comment: `http://localhost:8888/Website/who_we_are`, `http://localhost:8888/Website/home`, `http://localhost:8888/Website/contact` etc .... `http://localhost:8888/GroovyMovers/` works fine though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44711/discussion-between-anubhava-and-stefan-dunn)

Comment: Thank you for helping out and explaining it well :)